# My SDL_KEYUP argument isn't working

Tags: c++, sdl

I tried setting the arguments up in different ways, but still no dice. Could someone tell me what's going wrong here?

```
void controls()
{

if(cancontrol = true)
{

if(window_key.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
{
    switch(window_key.key.keysym.sym)
    {
    case SDLK_UP:
    haneposy =+ -1;
    haneposx = 0;
    break;

    case SDLK_LEFT:
    haneposx =- 1;
    haneposy = 0;
    break;

    case SDLK_RIGHT:
    haneposx =+ 1;
    haneposy = 0;
    break;

    case SDLK_DOWN:
    haneposy =- -1;
    haneposx = 0;
    break;
    default:
    break;
    }
}

if(window_key.type == SDL_KEYUP)
{
    switch(window_key.key.keysym.sym)
    {
    case SDLK_UP:
    haneposx = 0;
    haneposy = 0;
    break;

    case SDLK_LEFT:
    haneposx = 0;
    haneposy = 0;
    break;

    case SDLK_RIGHT:
    if(haneposx && haneposy > 0)
    {
    haneposx = 0;
    haneposy = 0;
    }
    break;

    case SDLK_DOWN:
    haneposx = 0;
    haneposy = 0;
    break;
    default:
    break;
    }
}
}

    }
```

The problem is that when the key is released it doesn't stop the sprite from moving by equaling the variable to zero. For additional information I am using glTranslate to move the sprite.

Comment: Is window_key an event?  What happens if you comment out the can_control if statement (just the one line: not the entire if statement).

Comment: Show us the entire method or at least where you get the event.

Comment: Consider using a if(type == SDL_KEYUP){...}else if(type SDL_KEYDOWN){..}, because when you are using just if, even if the first condition is true, your code will test the second condition too but you will never go into this block, because the type is clearly not SDL_KEYDOWN and its better for the performance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you confused += for =+. The first is an operator for increment and the second is an assignment followed by a plus sign.

Comment: SDL_KEYUP is still not responding.